# How to change shape of keras tensors during model building?

Tags: keras

I have an autoencoder model that looks like:

```python
input_img = Input(shape=(128, 128, 1))  
x = Conv2D(...)(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D(...)(x)
...
out = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid')(x)
my_model = Model(input_img, decoded)
my_model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss=my_custom_loss)
```

Currently, the shape of `out` is the same as `input_img`, let's say `(None, 128, 128, 1)`. I would like to manipulate `out` to have shape `(None, 128, 128, 2)`. The contents of that extra block are irrelevant.

In case anyone is wondering why I want to do this: it's because I intend to have some extra information in the ground truth values `y_true` so that I can define a specific cost function, `my_custom_loss`. It seems like in order to do this, the shape of `out` must match the shape of `y_true` when defining the cost function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contents are truly irrelevant you can pad it with zeros. It could look something like:

```
zeros = Lambda(lambda x: K.zeros_like(x))(out) # (None, 128, 128, 1)
out = Concatenate([out, zeros]) # (None, 128, 128, 2)
```

Make sure you ignore the extra padding you are adding.